# File "/tmp/ipykernel_17/4234813531.py",line4 librosa.display.specshow(log_power, x_axis='time', y_axis='mel', cmap=cm.jet) SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python

**Code:**

```
C = librosa.cqt(y, sr=sr, n_bins=84)
print('Transform shape', C.shape) 
log_power = librosa.amplitude_to_db((np.abs(S))(C**2, ref=np.max)
librosa.display.specshow(log_power, x_axis='time', y_axis='mel', cmap=cm.jet)
```

**Error:**

```
 error File "/tmp/ipykernel_17/4234813531.py", line 4
    librosa.display.specshow(log_power, x_axis='time', y_axis='mel', cmap=cm.jet)
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
          ^
```

Comment: You are missing a `)` on the line above, starting with `log_power=...`

Comment: Thanks Cory Kramer,I solved this error.